# xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image_and_name_reply always return null

Tags: xcb

there are too few document about xcb. I tried wait, xcb_flush etc.

```
let cookie = xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image_and_name_unchecked(conn);
                    loop {
let ptr = xcb_xfixes_get_cursor_image_and_name_reply(conn, cookie, std::ptr::null_mut());
```

> I have to use XFixesGetCursorImage directly, xcb seems buggy.

Comment: Could you provide a full code example that I can execute? Are you using `xcb_xfixes_query_version()` before trying to use the XFixes extension?

Answer (score 1):

You need to announce to the X11 server your supported version of the XFixes extension before you can use it. libxfixes automatically does this QueryVersion request for you, but libxcb does not do any magic behind your back.

The X11 server enforces that you can only use requests that match the version that you announced that you support:

```
static int
ProcXFixesDispatch(ClientPtr client)
{
    REQUEST(xXFixesReq);
    XFixesClientPtr pXFixesClient = GetXFixesClient(client);

    if (pXFixesClient->major_version >= ARRAY_SIZE(version_requests))
        return BadRequest;
    if (stuff->xfixesReqType > version_requests[pXFixesClient->major_version])
        return BadRequest;
    return (*ProcXFixesVector[stuff->xfixesReqType]) (client);
}
```

(Copied from https://sources.debian.org/src/xorg-server/2:1.20.8-2/xfixes/xfixes.c/?hl=135#L144)